Hello, i want to make a function in Maui 8.0 that snaps the scroll e.g. like when you are scrolling throw instagram reels or tiktok
private async void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    if (isSnapping)
        return;

    isSnapping = true;

    double scrollY = e.ScrollY;
    int currentRow = (int)(scrollY / SnapItemHeight);
    double snapTo;

    // Determine scroll direction and calculate the snap position accordingly
    if (scrollY > previousScrollY)
    {
        // Scrolling down
        snapTo = (currentRow + 1) * SnapItemHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        // Scrolling up
        snapTo = currentRow * SnapItemHeight;
    }

    // Ensure the snap position is within valid range
    snapTo = Math.Max(0, snapTo);

    // Small delay to ensure smooth snapping
    await Task.Delay(50);  // Reduced delay for smoother snapping

    // Snap to the calculated position
    await scrollView.ScrollToAsync(0, snapTo, true);

    // Update previous scroll position
    previousScrollY = scrollY;
    isSnapping = false;
}

 <ScrollView HeightRequest="100" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled" x:Name="scrollView">
     <!--Make the scroll Snap like its instagram reels-->
     <Grid x:Name="FriendsGrid" Padding="20" ColumnSpacing="-40" RowSpacing="10">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <!-- Add friend buttons (white circles) -->
         <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource FriendButtonStyle}" />
     </Grid>
 </ScrollView>

im trying to achieve this function but it looks ugly the scroll is going in the middle of the circles and its just messy i tried to give it to AI but it made it messier to be honest and im stuck now Any Suggestions would be lovely
 private const double SnapItemHeight = 80;
 private bool isSnapping;
 private double previousScrollY = 0;

and of course these to declare them
if it looked weird please let me know im 3 months into self taught mobile developments and i would love if there is any suggestions out side of this topic

CarouselView will do this for you

what's the meaning of throw instagram reels or tiktok? can you provide relevant view screenshot of your project?

Does it help? .NET MAUI Vertically SwipeView tiktok slide etc.
